golang mongo driver error alway nil when wrong port
My code:
func main() {    
    ctx := context.Background()  
    uri := "mongodb://localhost:12345"   
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to MongoDB:", err)
        // Handle the error here, likely indicating a connection issue or wrong port
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")  
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)     
}

err return nil when connection issue or wrong port 12345
